# How to get spacy to read through an entire column in a data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, spacy

This is the code that I used but instead of going through a single sentence I want it to code through a column in my data frame called "full_text"

```
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm") 
doc = nlp('el secretario de estado de eeuu')
for token in doc:
   print(token.text, token.pos_,)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) for this, in your case:

```py
# prior loaded dataframe called `df`

nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm") 

raw_docs = (row.full_text for row in df.itertuples())

for doc in nlp.pipe(raw_docs):
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.pos_)
    # whatever else you want to do per doc
```

This will process the texts row-wise using a generator, so only one of them is loaded into memory at once, rather than recreating the column as a list using something like `raw_docs = df["full_text"].tolist()`.